# Backing up from Google Photos

Tags: google-photos, backup, online-backup

There was a time when web storage was the secondary/backup place for me to keep all my digital photos. Nowadays Google Photos is not only my primary place but the ONLY place I keep my photos. This has led me to think what would happen if my account was compromised and somebody went on and delete all my photos from my Google account. It would be devastating.

Is there a way I can keep a secondary place for all my photos what works automatically, meaning I don't want any manual steps to keep it synchronised?

Perhaps I can invest in a local NAS or another web service like Dropbox or OneDrive.

How would I set up such synchronisation?

Answer (score 1):

Like Google Photos, you can [Back up photos & videos automatically in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6093613).

But Google recommend backing up using one app to avoid storing duplicate.